# Does the location of Great Works matter?

Tags: civilization-5, civilization-5-brave-new-world

You can move your great works around in the culture overview screen, but is there any benefit?

Does the number of works in a city matter? Is there some kind of exponential bonus?
Does it matter if it is closer to foreign boarders, as in the tourists don't have to travel as far to be influenced?

I can understand that if a city is under attack it is nice that you can get all your stuff out of there before it is taken over. Is that the only tangible benefit?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The number of Great Works in a given city does not, in and of itself, make a difference, nor do the location of the city, nor the nature of the work, but once you start getting buildings with more than one slot, there is the opportunity for [Theming Bonuses](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/123744/50582) if you have multiple Great Works in the same building, meeting certain conditions.

As well, there are a number of different effects from various buildings, wonders, or civilizations' unique abilities, which can provide bonuses to tourism generated in a given city, so stacking multiple Great Works in a city with such bonuses will mean more Great Works getting the bonus.

Lastly, any time a city is captured, any Great Works still in that city are also captured, which makes border cities a little riskier. However, because you can move Great Works instantly across any distance as long as it's your turn, you can usually move them out when a city is under siege and losing, before it's taken, as long as you remember.

Comment: keep in mind or add to your answer if a city is taken w.e great works are located in that city are gained by the opposing civ

Comment: I've added that in, thanks! I normally wouldn't think of that, since I generally move them out of the city just in time, and my border cities usually aren't the ones with wonders for theming bonuses, so it's never had an impact, but for some players, I imagine this might be an issue.

Comment: They produce culture and that is affected by city's culture modifier, so its best to have as much as possible in city with hermitage (or other culture % boosting building, ideally all of them in single city)

Answer (score 0):

On its own, the location of the great work has no relevance. Any great work, from *any* civ or era, generates the same values of Tourism and Culture, regardless of what city or even what building it is in.

However, there are numerous buildings and effects that might make one city preferred. The *National Visitor Center* National Wonder, for instance, makes works in the city generate extra tourism, and France's new Unique Ability gives Tourism bonuses to the capital.